# Prism: How to get the view name from RegionManager?

Tags: wpf, prism

I am using Prims 5 and I can register a view in a RegionManager this way:

```
region.Add(view, "hello")
```

Now, I want to retrieve the name of that view from my RegionManager. I would need something like:

```
regionManager.Regions("MainRegion").Views.FirstOrDefault().Name
```

But Name does not match with "hello", it is the XAML UserControl x:Name (from the view).

The question is: how can I retrieve the "hello" name from regionManager?

Thank you

Comment: You can try like this ((HelloView)regionManager.Regions("MainRegion").GetView("hello")).Name

Comment: What I want to get is "hello" string, the name (string) I wrote when I added the view to the region. I cannot send it like a parameter, because it is precisely what I want to get. Thank you anyway

Comment: You can't access the text string in that way. Why do you need to access the text string? If you can explain what you are trying to achieve I am sure there is an alternative method to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Jason I am adding the views in a region inside a TabControl. So I can instanciate twice, or three times the same view in different tabItems. When I am going to add the view I test if "hello" view exists and then I add "hello2", "hello3", and so. When I call the "close button" I need to know which one I must close. So I need to know the view name ("hello", "hello2"...), so I can call GetView("hello"), and remove it. Thank you

Comment: Perhaps look into using both the INavigationAware and IActiveAware interfaces? You use the INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget method to control when new views are created (or existing views reused) and the IsActive property from IActiveAware tells you which view is active.

Comment: @Jason I can implement IActiveAware interface, but it does not work properly, because if we have two views, each one with a close button in its TabItem header and we press the button in the active view, it works right, but if we press the button in the other one, the IActiveAware interface updates after the command is executed, so we close the wrong view. That is why I was trying to get the name and close it with view.remove(viewName). Thank you

Comment: Are you using a Trigger Action to deal with the closing of the view, or are you handling the close in the View model?  If you are using the viewmodel, then search for an article that uses a CloseTabbedViewAction from David Hill. He provides a complete example showing tab navigation. The tab closing is based upon a separate Trigger action.